# DLL compiled in Visual Studio 2015 throws 0xc000007b error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

It drives me crazy. I want to create a basic DLL hook (for strictly informational purposes, etc)

My program is 32bit and so the DLL I'm compiling.

So I made empty DLL project in Visual Studio 2015 (just to check if my program picks it up) and I set "output filename" to dinput8.dll

After compilation,  when my program tries to load this DLL it throws

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the Application

Yes, I've installed both 64bit and 32bit versions of VC++ Runtime 2015. What's even more weird is the fact that the same DLL code works fine when compiled in Code::Blocks (MinGW)

Comment: This is most likely a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit modules. Are you sure you are loading the 32-bit dll that you just built? Also, you mentioned "hook" in your post; are you by mistake hooking some 64-bit process?

Comment: @VladFeinstein Yes, I'm 100% Sure. Also, I just used Dependency walker and it tells me I'm missing API-MS-WIN-CRT-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL and a couple of other API-MS-WIN-CRT- DLL's. I'm on windows 10 and I cannot find them anywhere for my system...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a lot of research, it turned out that the problem was that the the DLL I was injecting was a dummy and didn't have any exports. Looks like at least one export is required, so I made a dummy export

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) void dummyExp();

....
void dummyExp()
{
}
```

and now  everything works fine.